# How to set lower bound for random values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, random, generator

I want to insert multiple random values into one of my columns. However I don't want small values like 1.5 and so on. How do I set the lower bound for random numbers?
For now I do it as follows:

```
delimiter $$  
create procedure randomizer()
begin
  declare i int Default 0 ;
  myloop: loop
  Insert into Tax  (id, amount) 
  VALUES (i+1, ROUND(RAND() * 1000,2));
  set i=i+1;
      if i=1000 then
      leave myloop;
end if;
end loop myloop;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a lower bound, you just need to shift the values up by whatever min amount.

```
Insert into Tax  (id, amount) 
VALUES (i+1, ROUND(RAND() * 980,2) + 20 );
```

The above code will insert a random number between 20 and 1000